Unable to deserialize from object mapper, getting error "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException
So I am new to RestAssured API automation, I was trying to create json from pojo class through object mapper though  I am successfully able to create json from pojo but getting error when trying to deserialize to java object through object mapper with below error at step(List<Person> latest=map.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Person>>() {
});) :
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type java.util.ArrayList<org.example.Details>from Object value (tokenJsonToken.START_OBJECT)  at [Source: REDACTED (StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1767)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1541)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1488)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:396)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:252)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:342)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4899)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3846)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3829)
at org.example.CreateNestedJson.generatePayload(CreateNestedJson.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:136)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:658)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:219)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:923)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:192)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:808)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:603)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:429)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:423)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:383)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:326)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1249)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1169)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1092)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1060)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:65)
at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:105)`

My payload:
{   "person" : [ {     "id" : 11,     "name" : "John",     "city" : "NewYork",     "phone" : "7647388372",     "facebook" : "JohnTheGreat"   } ]
My POJO classes:
Root class
package org.example;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
public class NewAPITest {
List<Person> person=new ArrayList<>();
public void setPerson(List person){
    this.person=person;
}
public List<Person> getPerson(){
    return person;
}

}
nested class
 package org.example;

    public class Person {
      int id;
      String name;
      String city;
      String phone;
      String facebook;

public String getFacebook() {
    return facebook;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public void setFacebook(String facebook) {
    this.facebook = facebook;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
    }

class which serialize and deserialize
package org.example;

 import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
 import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
 import io.restassured.RestAssured;
 import org.testng.annotations.Test;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

   public class CreateNestedJson {
   @Test
   public void generatePayload() throws JsonProcessingException {

    Person person=new Person();
    person.setId(11);
    person.setCity("NewYork");
    person.setFacebook("JohnTheGreat");
    person.setPhone("7647388372");
    person.setName("John");

    List<Person>list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(person);
    NewAPITest object=new NewAPITest();
    object.setPerson(list);

    ObjectMapper map=new ObjectMapper();
    String json=map.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(object);
    System.out.println(json);
    **List<Person> latest=map.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<Person>>() {
    });** // this line where I am getting error
    for (Person s:latest) {
        System.out.println("Name " + s.getId());
        System.out.println("Age " + s.getName());
        System.out.println("Age " + s.getCity());
        System.out.println("Age " + s.getPhone());
        System.out.println("Age " + s.getFacebook());
    }
}
}

I was trying to create json from pojo class through object mapper though  I am successfully able to create json from pojo but getting error when trying to deserialize to java object through object mapper, it should be deserialize when I am able to serialize,
not sure what am i doing wrong?
